# Approximating the number of lines in an arbitrarily large file and calculating error/confidence?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, error

First off, let me know if this is in the wrong stack exchange I wasn't sure where exactly to ask this.

Okay so I came up with a scheme to figure out how to how many lines are in an arbitrarily large file:

1. Sample *X* number of *random* lines from a file
2. Find the average length (size in bytes) of the sampled lines (i.e. bytes of sample / *X*)
3. Find the number of lines in the file using the approximated average length (i.e. bytes of entire file / avg bytes per line)

So basically, how can I figure out what the the error is and how accurate this strategy is? And is there a way to figure out what *X* should be?

Thanks so much and sorry if I'm butchering terminology!

EDIT: Got rid of the previous edits that got this question a little off topic.

Comment: Interesting as an academic exercise perhaps, but did you know that simply entering "wc *filename*" at the command line (or in a Cygwin Windows terminal) will give you the exact line count in a very short period of time? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/count-lines-in-a-file. I can't think of a reason why you'd want to wait longer for a less accurate answer.

Comment: This is the right way to ask such a question.  The problematic questions are formulated by those who try to emulate statistical (or worse, mathematical) terminology and end up getting everything totally confused to the point where nobody understands anything that is said.  When you can give us a clear statement of your problem in your own words, then we can have confidence that at least one side of the conversation knows what they're writing about!

Comment: i think computationally it'll be more efficient to sample X number of bytes rather than lines. then identify number of sentences in them to estimate the number for entire file. reading files is done in byte blocks, not lines.

Comment: @NuclearWang yeah I know about wc. The files I'm working with could potentially be >20GB though and I was worried about it taking too long since (I think) wc is O(n)

Comment: @Aksakal I'm not totally sure what you mean by "sentence". The files I'm working with here are logs of networking connections were each row/line is a different connection. I guess I could take sentence to be determined by where \n is but still the connections are temporally related so I think taking a contiguous chunk of bytes would hurt accuracy. I'll add this info in an edit!

Comment: @MargoOka, I apologize, meant "lines" not "sentences"

Comment: @Aksakal no worries :)

Comment: @Aksakal Bear in mind a byte-sampling approach requires an appropriately weighted estimate, because the chance of including any line in a sample is directly proportional to its length.

Comment: @whuber, I'd study the distribution of number of lines in log files based on the existing log files, then determine the appropriate size of the sample in bytes

Comment: In case OP is wondering why so many people have commented but not answered -- the temporal relationships between the lines in the file implies non-independence of lengths of adjacent lines. How important non-independence is to answering your question depends on how zeek logs work and what the particular computer is doing (for example, is the user struggling to use python's `requests` library correctly?). Strong dependence between lines would need to be accounted for, but if the lines were truly *independent*, then some elementary solutions would suffice.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica tbh I care more about figuring out how to analyze the error of this strategy rather than what is actually the best way to do it so maybe I should reword the question hmm...

Comment: @Aksakal That's not the issue: it's important to estimate the number of lines correctly.  I'm just warning the OP against making the (great) mistake of scaling up a line count from a byte sample.  This also goes to the main concern of the OP, which is estimating the error: the error estimate depends both on the sampling strategy and the estimation procedure.

Comment: Non-independence of lines is directly related correctly estimating the number of lines and the error because it informs the probability model to use. If you want a right answer, you have to use an appropriate tool to compute it.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica I'm fine with that but
I mean the question itself is still answerable since I was since asking about calculating error and confidence. I only started talking about runtime and why I was asking this question because people kept telling me to use wc. Disregarding runtime I think it's still an interesting question but it's usefulness is questionable

Comment: I agree that the statistical content is interesting. Perhaps you could edit the question so that from beginning to end, it reads as a coherent question without the impossible constraints. You don't need to append information as "EDIT: blah" because anyone who wants to see an old version of the question can just look at the edit history. Right now, it's hard to tell what you want answered and within what limits.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica ah okay I think I'll do that